# Using a column containing NULL in MySQL Full Text Search

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

In code as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM products
 WHERE MATCH (title, sdescription, ldescription) AGAINST ('iphone case 4s');
```

What happens if a row has NULL value for either of title, sdescription and ldescription? Will the MySQL engine ignore it or will it return a lot of false positives?

Comment: You should consider accepting the answer below if it solved your problem, by clicking on the check mark!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the purposes of MySQL FULLTEXT indexes, `NULL` is treated the same as an empty string. That query would not return false positives based on the presence of NULL values.